# How to group by categories in LDAP using PHP

Tags: php, sorting, ldap, ldap-query

How to group or arrange the results in LDAP according to "ou". OU have 4 or more categories and display it properly. How to do this with PHP and HTML? Please help me. I'm new in LDAP

OU example

```
   ou=web service
   ou=department
   ou=city
```

How to do display the result like this?

```
   sn     dn                                        mail                 ou
   user   cn=user,ou=web service,dc=domain,dc=com   example@domain.com   web service
   sn     dn                                        mail                 ou
   user   cn=user,ou=department,dc=domain,dc=com   example@domain.com    department
```

Here's the PHP array

```
  $dn = 'dc=domain,dc=com';
  $filter = "(|(sn=$person*)(fullname=$person*))";
  $ldaparray = array ("ou", "sn", "fullname", "mail");
  $sr=ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter, $ldaparray);
  $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r ($info);
  echo "</pre>";
```

Output using print_r

```
Array
(
[count] => 1409
[0] => Array
    (
        [sn] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [0] => user
            )

        [0] => sn
        [count] => 1
        [dn] => cn=username,ou=web service,dc=domain,dc=com
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [sn] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [0] => user
            )

        [0] => sn
        [mail] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [0] => example@domain.com
            )

        [1] => mail
        [count] => 2
        [dn] => uid=userid,ou=department,dc=doamin,dc=com
    )
```

Comment: This question is about parsing & sorting an array. First of all you have to process the `dn` string first and use PHP array sorting methods to re-arrange your array.

Comment: That has no connection with ldap;apply the sorting on array using forloop and display

Comment: Can you pls help me with this? I'm not good in PHP